# Font Face Not Working on one section of Mobile

Tags: css, mobile, shopify, font-face

I'm using a custom font for Shopify which I've added to my css file. I used another font on this site as well and every place that I've inserted this font has worked just fine on desktop and mobile. The only place I want to use this second font (Arial Black) is in the section header.

I inserted this in my CSS but it doesn't appear on mobile, only on desktop:

```
       @font-face {
          font-family:  'Arial Black', sans-serif; 
           src: url({{'Arial_Black.ttf'| asset_url }});
                url({{'Arial-Black.woff'| asset_url }});
                url({{'Arial-Black.woff2'| asset_url }});
                url({{'Arial_Black.otf'| asset_url }}); 
           font-weight: normal;

    .section-header h2 {
     font-family: "Arial Black", sans-serif !important;
     font-weight: 900 !important;
     font-size: 30px ; 
        }
```

Any idea on how I can make this font work for just this one section of my site for mobile?

Answer (score 0):

Is that path for the font right? I would try using an absolute path just in case. If you aren't sure of the path check another pages' sources tab in the developer tools (one where it is working) and you'll find the path.

Edit:

Just checked, when in mobile there's a style rule that sets the headers to

```
.h1, .h2, h1, h2 {
margin: 0 0 17.5px;
font-family: var(--font-stack-header);
font-style: var(--font-style-header);
font-weight: var(--font-weight-header);
line-height: 1.2;
overflow-wrap: break-word;
word-wrap: break-word;
```

}

you need to add the following to your css to override this (I'm applying it only to h2 but if you want you can add h1):

```
h2, .h2 {
     font-family:  'Arial Black', Gadget, sans-serif !important;
}
```

This should fix it

Comment: I used that path because the font files were uploaded as an "asset" on Shopify. Could you explain what you mean by another pages sources tab?

Comment: When you upload that asset, does it give you the url of the asset?

The sources tab is part of the developer tools but don't worry about that. Do you mind linking the page where it does work and the one where it doesn't?

Comment: When I upload it it doesn't give a direct link, I just input the URL to the asset itself which is usually just the name of the file itself. I'm just confused because I used this exact same code for another site of mine (different font though) and all font changes appeared on mobile as well :(

Comment: Maybe something is overwriting the style on mobile like a media query. If you press right click on the text that isn't changing and select inspect element we may try to figure out whats happening.

Comment: I can check it if you direct me to the exact url of the page that isnt working but please remove your password because you never know who will use it to enter with malicious intent!

Comment: I've just poked around and added an option to my answer. Please rememeber to change your password because if posted here it is now insecure.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking a look at it!! I actually came across that too when I opened up the inspect tool, but strangely enough I can't find it anywhere in my css file? I just tried the code you posted and it didn't seem to change the mobile

Comment: I remember seeing it came from a file called password, maybe it isn't in your css but a plugin or smthng. I had an error in my css, I have corrected it! Try it again sorry.